# Grouping and ordering by value, alphabet and frequency based on common value

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, group-by

So I am working with MS Access and have this participant list With three columns age, name and age_group and want it first ordered by name and then by age and also by frequency of the age_group based on the same name. For example:

```
age | age_group |name  
----------------------
1      0-1        Jeff
10     10=<       Dave
10     10=<       Dave
5      5-7        Carl
2      2-4        Sam
3      2-4        Carl
4      2-4        Sam
2      2-4        Sam
5      5-7        Carl
6      5-7        Jeff
7      5-7        Dave
10     10=<       Jeff
8      8-9        Jeff
```

So it first would look like this, ordered by name and by age

```
----------------------
10     10=<       Jeff
8      8-9        Jeff
6      5-7        Jeff
1      0-1        Jeff
10     10=<       Dave
10     10=<       Dave
7      5-7        Dave
5      5-7        Carl
5      5-7        Carl
3      2-4        Carl
4      2-4        Sam
2      2-4        Sam
2      2-4        Sam
```

And finally by age_group frequency in descending order 10=<, 8-9, 5-7, 2-4, 0-1, based on the same name. Frequency meaning how many times the age group is present in any subset of name. For example age group 10=< is present two times in subset Dave.

```
age | age_group |name  
----------------------
10     10=<       Dave
10     10=<       Dave
7      5-7        Dave
10     10=<       Jeff
8      8-9        Jeff
6      5-7        Jeff
1      0-1        Jeff
5      5-7        Carl
5      5-7        Carl
3      2-4        Carl
4      2-4        Sam
2      2-4        Sam
2      2-4        Sam
```

Is this possible to do in SQL or VBA? I get the first one to work with:

```
SELECT participants.name, participants.age_group, participants.age, *
FROM participants
ORDER BY participants.name, participants.age DESC;
```

But I am totally lost in performing the second step...
Would appreciate if you could help me out.

Comment: I am just baffled on what YOU mean by "age group frequency".  And why Carl's rows are not adjacent but all the other names are.

Comment: @blazingfirefly ... have you checked my answer? If it is ok please mark it as correct. If not let me know and I´ll try to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fancy SQL will provide the grouped output:

```sql
SELECT 
    T3.age, T3.age_group, T3.name
FROM 
    Participants As T3
INNER JOIN

    (SELECT [age] * 1000 + Count(*) AS rating, T.name
    FROM participants AS T 
    INNER JOIN 

        (SELECT Max(participants.age) AS maxage, participants.name
        FROM participants
        GROUP BY participants.name) AS T2 

    ON (T.age = T2.maxage) AND (T.name = T2.name)
    GROUP BY T.name, T.age
    ORDER BY [age] * 1000 + Count(*) DESC) AS T4

ON T3.name = T4.name
ORDER BY T4.rating Desc, T3.age Desc
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Does sadly not work. I adjusted the example and question to be more precise.

Comment: Done ... but I think mine is more accurate to the question.

Comment: @Ibai: Thanks. However, I did try your version, but it doesn't run for me in Access.

Comment: I´ve tried in SQLServer and it works. Anyway, your's is fine.

Comment: I first got error that Access "Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object". That is when I noticed that the field: age was set up as long text. Changed that to numeric and now it works like a charm! Thank you very much for all your contribution. =) I marked the answer as final. And I apologize if my question was formulated a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select p1.name, p2.age_group, p2.age
from participants as p1
left join (select name, age_group, count(1) as freq from participants group by name, age_group) as p2
on p1.name= p2.name and p1.age_group = p2.age_group
order by name,age, p2.freq desc
```

Access:

```sql
select p1.name, p1.age_group, p1.age
from participants as p1
left join 

(select name, age_group, count(1) as freq 
from participants group by name, age_group) as p2

on p1.name= p2.name and p1.age_group = p2.age_group
order by p1.name, p1.age, p2.freq desc
```

Access output:

[image: Access]

Comment: I tried to modify it for Access, but the sorting of the output is not as intended.

Comment: :^/ the ordering must be Name, Age asc and p2.freq desc .. note that the example is not consistent with the requisites.

Comment: Sense or not - to me it doesn't look like the requested output - see attached screenshot, please.

Comment: The attached screenshot is correct as it is asked. The question is a little bit tricky ;)

Comment: Please notice, that the questioneer did improve the explanation, though the requested output, apart from a minor correction, hasn't changed.

Comment: Buffff .... wht a disaster :P Anyway both answers resolves the "jam" xD Question is wrongly defined.